# What does this mean: [ x[1:] for x in self.files if x != '/']

Tags: python, functional-programming

What does this mean:

```
[x[1:] for x in self.files if x != '/']
```

If possible would you mind explaining it in imperative equivalent?

Comment: The functional version of this would be `map(lambda s: s[1:], filter(partial(ne, '/'), self.files))`. Notice how each function's output is dependent only upon its input and there are no side effects. What you have is just a simple list comprehension.

Comment: Ah so it's not a functional 'paradigm'  BUT it's getting closer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see the expression one step at a time. This part returns a list of files in the current object:

```
self.files
```

Now let's iterate over the list and call `x` each element in turn:

```
for x in self.files
```

But let's not take all of them, let's just consider those that are not called `'/'`:

```
for x in self.files if x != '/'
```

For each of the files that pass the filter, let's remove the first character in the file's name:

```
x[1:] for x in self.files if x != '/'
```

And finally, let's put the results in a new list:

```
[x[1:] for x in self.files if x != '/']
```

FYI, what we just did it's called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). As pointed by @PasteBT and @aga, the code is equivalent to this explicit loop:

```
ans = []                  # create a new empty list
for x in self.files:      # iterate over it, using x as variable
    if x != '/':          # if the element is not 'x'
        ans.append(x[1:]) # add it after removing 1st char
```

Now `ans` will contain the same list as the one returned by the list comprehension.

Comment: YOU SIR are a gentleman a scholar and a scientist.  I shall call you el flamo blanco. Thanks for the help! I was getting thrown off by the remove the first character step becuase it's just kind of sitting there out front with no indication of which processing step it's operating on.  Plus I'm a noob to functional programming.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It's [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which constructs a new list which elements are slices of filenames in the variable `self.files` excluding the filename of root directory. Each slice consists of `n-1` letters in a filename, from the second (where second letter in a string has index of 1) to the last.
An imperative equivalent of this code will be a little bit more verbose:

```
lst = []
for x in self.files:
    if x != "/":
        lst.append(x[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

same as:

```
ret = []
for x in self.files:
    if x != '/':
        ret.append(x[1:])
return ret
```

Comment: Thank! This is exactly what I was looking for.  Combining this with the above step de-rustled my jimmies.